# Using same AWS EFS to share multiple directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have create a file system EFS and mount on a EC2 instance on /var/www/html/media. I would like to use the same EFS Filesystem to mount another directory /var/www/html/var.

Is that possible?

I would do:

```
fs-296e0282.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/media   /var/www/html/media   nfs4    defaults

fs-296e0282.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/var   /var/www/html/var   nfs4    defaults
```

But it seems not possible.

Comment: https://boognish.io/2018/07/02/magento-network-elastic-file-system-efs-on-aws/
I think I found a way!

Comment: Couldn't you just create a symbolic link?

Comment: How are u planning to do that?

Comment: [How to Create Symbolic Links in Linux Using the ln Command | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/)

Comment: I got guys! tks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to mount two different directories under file mount system. Initially in order to access your efs just mount a EFS root under your instance using the command

```
Sudo mount -t efs fs-id:/ /home/efs
```

Then create subdirectories under the /home/efs folder for example let's have two subdirectories under /home/efs namely media and var

Now you can mount two directories in  /var/www/html/media and /var/www/html/var by adding the below in fstab file which will be under /etc/

```
fs-id:/media /var/www/html/media efs defaults,_netdev 0 0

fs-id:/var /var/www/html/var efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

And reboot your instance. Whatever changes in /var/www/html/media will gets reflected in fs-id:/media folder also the same applies for var folder also hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your EFS id: `fs-357f69c8`

You want to mount in a EC2 Machine of following folders

- `/efs`
- `/var/www/html/data`
- `/var/www/html/api/upload`
- `/var/www/html/uploadetfiles`

So, first, create the folders

- `sudo mkdir /efs`
- `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/data`
- `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/api/upload`
- `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/uploadetfiles`

For mount in EC2 command will be

- `sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-357f69c8:/ /efs`
- `sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-357f69c8:/ /var/www/html/data`
- `sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-357f69c8:/ /var/www/html/api/upload`
- `sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-357f69c8:/ /var/www/html/uploadetfiles`

**NB:
Your machine should have `efs-utils` installed**

To build and install an RPM:

- `sudo yum -y install git rpm-build make`
- `sudo git clone https://github.com/aws/efs-utils`
- `cd efs-utils`
- `sudo make rpm`
- `sudo yum -y install build/amazon-efs-utils*rpm`

To build and install a Debian package:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get -y install git binutils`
- `sudo git clone https://github.com/aws/efs-utils`
- `cd efs-utils`
- `sudo ./build-deb.sh`
- `sudo apt-get -y install ./build/amazon-efs-utils*deb`

Hope this will works