# Showing only one FileSystem when mounting multiple folders to EFS

Tags: amazon-efs

I read the post,  [Using same AWS EFS to share multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260276/using-same-aws-efs-to-share-multiple-directories). But when I view the disk usage from the command line, I only see the most recent volume that I mounted.

I first install the EFS helper and then try to mount two directories:

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
sudo mount -t efs fs-0f12ef3456a78b90c /home/ec2-user
sudo mount -t efs fs-0f12ef3456a78b90c /var/www/html
```

When I do `df -h` from the command line I get:

```
fs-0f12ef3456a78b90c.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E  580M  8.0E   1% /var/www/html
```

Whether I use the documentation found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-nfs-permissions-per-user-subdirs.html or the commands that I gave above I get the same thing, only one line showing that a file system is mounted.

Are all of the sub directories being mounted or just the most recent that I added?

Answer (score 0):

Like most things, this is resolved by actually reading the documentation on the mount command.  A listing of all the mounted volumes is displayed with:

```
findmnt
```